# How to join two polygon layers into a resulting layer with overlapping polygons merged together (including attributes)

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, grass-gis

I am trying to find a method (in QGIS and/or GRASS) to join two layers of polygons into a resulting layer with merged overlapping polygons. It's hard to explain in words, so I've drawn a simplified graphic

[image]

Has anyone come up with a working solution for this need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do such operations with [v.overlay](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.overlay.html). In the online manual, see the example "EXAMPLE POLYGON TO POLYGON UNION. Polygon union of urban area and Census 2000 areas (North Carolina dataset)" which is similar to your request.